# Does it matter if I append the secret to the salt or pass it in separately?

Tags: pbkdf-2, salt

I'm using PBKDF2, and this is my current call.

```
key = pbkdf2-hmac-sha256(iterations = 100_000, secret = password ++ salt)
```

I recently learnt that the function I'm calling also takes an optional `salt` field, and passing the salt instead of appending it gives different answers. Is what I'm currently doing insecure? I don't think it is, but I want to be safe - it looks like PBKDF2 uses the secret many times, but the salt only once, and there might be a good reason for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have been doing is unconventional, but is cryptographically safe, and should be fine as long as the implementation of `pbkdf2-hmac-sha256` is correct. Things to watch out:

- is all the stuff (characters?) in `password` and `salt` safely kept by whatever `++` is?
- is this `secret` then converted to octets without entropy loss on entry of `pbkdf2-hmac-sha256` ? Changing anything non-ASCII to `?` is a [goof that has crept](https://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/1002-advisories/jbcrypt-entropy.txt); combined with use of a foreign language, overly paranoid user, or an [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem, that could degenerate to the *length* of the secret being the only entropy left! Another issue that can creep is stopping at the first zero octet in `secret`.
- Does the `pbkdf2-hmac-sha256` implementation correctly handle the case when `secret`, converted to octets, exceeds 64 octets? The action `pbkdf2-hmac-sha256` should perform in this case is to replace these octets with their 32-octet SHA-256 hash.

Given this, the worst I can think the unconventional use of `pbkdf2-hmac-sha256`could cause is that timing execution could leak the length of `password` in an easier manner, but that's a non-issue.

Before that [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/136004), I knew no language where 100_000 is a valid constant. More importantly, a hundred thousands is an insufficient iteration count nowadays for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-256, a short memorable password, and protecting a key from exhaustive search. Modern password-based key derivation functions make use of memory, sometime multiple execution threads, to greatly increase their effectiveness at a given execution time or cost, e.g. [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2), [Balloon](https://crypto.stanford.edu/balloon/).

Note: implementing the core of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-256 in something that ultimately is interpreted rather than somewhat compiled would be a huge (but not rare) design mistake, since it would force using a lower iteration count than would be otherwise possible.

Comment: "_I can't remember using a language where 100_000_" Java and Ruby allow this (there may be others) but neither appears to use `++` as concatenation. Haskell and erlang seem to alloy `++` but I've not _seen_ that they allow underscores in numbers (but I don't _know_ they don't!)